# Need an option to make my angular app downloadable

Tags: angular

I need a recommendation on what i can do to allow users to download my project from my angular app, its basically a templating app, I want my users to hit the download button on my app and the whole website will get downloaded to them including the assets, also if possible i want to define a list from assets which will get downloaded and not everything. Thanks

Comment: well, that why you have GitHub\BitBucket etc...
just upload your code there and give a link :)

Comment: No actually i want the user to download the template which he has created or customized, which will only be available on runtime

Comment: ok, well that a bit more complicated.
I dont see any way for you to be able to do so.
Hope that I`m wrong. Good Luck.

Comment: If I understand, you want that the "core" of your own project to be downlodable, with the template the user created? If so, please make it clear in the question itself. I suggest that the core part is a .zip file already made. For the template, you'll need to generate the files and write them in a folder (preferably a temporary one) and find a tool to zip it. Then the download can start. Just be cautious about folders permissions etc

Comment: "you want that the "core" of your own project to be downlodable, with the template the user created ", Yes you're correct, but how do i generate the files and put it in a folder?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not really a tutorial site, and even less a free coding service. You are supposed to show an attempt to solve your problem yourself and ask specific questions about what doesn't work. We currently have no idea of the language you are using server-side, how you templates are generated, etc. If you have no idea, start step by step and search how to write files in your server language, if template is only client-side, how to send it to your server, etc..